# Free SNMP simulator tools?

Tags: snmp, simulator

Lately I have gotten into SNMP agent development and have been using the 30 day free trial of ireasoning's snmpd simulator. The tool has proven immensely handy, it can act as an snmpd service providing random/specified data for mib(s). While I would love for my employer to buy this tool, that doesn't seem very likely at the moment. So, I was wondering if any free alternatives exist that I could use instead?

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so handy but I used tu use the [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) open source SNMP server. you can simulate part of MIBS with script code or EXE files. It represents some work, but it's doable. I don't know about open source simulator.

Answer (score 8):

Try this one: http://snmpsim.sf.net

This is basically a SNMP Agent that reports back static values as taken from its backend (text files). You could either dump a snapshot of a real SNMP agent into a text file for snmpsim or create them from the scratch.

The tool is cross-platform and SNMP v3 capable.

Comment: I've merged your four accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/1228)

Comment: Is there any online SNMP simulator?

Answer (score 4):

I have recently written an SNMP v1 simulator in golang. I have written a simple programming language to specify OID variables and how they change. In one example, I used it to simulate a printer for page counts and error changes. Its aim is more about focusing on particular OIDs of interest than basing off an SNMP dump (which some other simulators do).

The project can be found here: https://github.com/scorptec68/snmprun

The docs are here: https://github.com/scorptec68/snmprun/wiki

The download is here: https://github.com/scorptec68/snmprun/releases

Answer (score 3):

You can also try [www.gambitcomm.com](http://www.gambitcomm.com), they provide SNMP Simulator for Single device version for Free.

Comment: Is there any online SNMP simulator? –

Comment: snmp.live.gambitcommunications.com has a simulated Cisco router. public read community string.

Answer (score 1):

open source and free implementation of SNMP agents simulator:
https://github.com/inexio/snmpsim

Features:

- SNMPv1/v2c/v3 support
- SNMPv3 USM supports MD5/SHA/SHA224/SHA256/SHA384/SHA512 auth and DES/3DES/AES128/AES192/AES256 privacy crypto algorithms
- Runs over IPv4 and/or IPv6 transports
- Simulates many EngineID's, each with its own set of simulated objects
- Varies response based on SNMP Community, Context, source/destination addresses and ports
- Can gather and store snapshots of SNMP Agents for later simulation
- Can run simulation based on MIB files, snmpwalk and sapwalk output
- Can gather simulation data from network traffic or tcpdump snoops
- Can gather simulation data from external program invocation or a SQL database
- Can trigger SNMP TRAP/INFORMs on SET operations
- Capable to simultaneously simulate tens of thousands of Agents
- Offers REST API based control plane
- Gathers and reports extensive activity metrics
- Pure-Python, easy to deploy and highly portable
- Can be extended by loadable Python snippets

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [this one](http://www.veraxsystems.com/en/products/snmpsimulator) it's free and can simulate `SNMPv1/v2c` agents.

Comment: NOTE: Free Version Allows to simulate only one device.

Answer (score 0):

I've used AgentX++ from snmp++,  It has a master sample and by changing that you can make your own Agent. from this link [agent++](https://agentpp.com)